# How can I render date in the browser using Day.js?

Tags: javascript, web-frontend, dayjs

I want to render a date into the `<span class="mr-3 text-danger date">` element using Dayjs. How do I go about doing this? I have dayjs imported from a CDN in a script tag at the bottom of the html document.

```
<!--This is my html code-->
<div class="d-flex event">
    <span class="mr-3 text-danger date"></span>
    <span class="text-danger">24°C, Fort Portal</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <!--This is my html code-->
        <div class="d-flex event">
            <span class="mr-3 text-danger date"></span><br>
            <span class="text-danger">24°C, Fort Portal</span>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/dayjs@1.8.21/dayjs.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        let datesClasses = document.getElementsByClassName("date")

        Array.prototype.forEach.call(datesClasses, element => {
    
            element.innerHTML = dayjs().format('YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss A')

        })
    </script>
</html>
```