# Showing how long ago a post was made in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, time, frontend, dayjs

I would like to show website views when an article was posted i.e, 1 hour ago, 4 ,mins ago, 2 years ago, etc.
I would like to use DAY.JS to do the task.

```
<!--This is my html & bootstrap code-->

<div>
    <h1 class="font-weight-600 mb-1">
        President Donald Trump tests positive of coronavirus.
    </h1>
    <p class="fs-13 text-muted mb-0">
        <span class="mr-2">Photo </span> 10 Minutes ago
    </p>
    <div class="rotate-img">
        <img src="../assets/images/news/trump-tests-positive.jpeg"
            alt="banner"
            class="img-fluid mt-4 mb-4"/>
    </div>
    <p class="mb-4 fs-15">
        US President Donald Trump and First Lady Melania Trump
        tested positive for COVID-19, he said in a tweet early
        on Friday.
    </p>
    <p>"We will begin our quarantine and recovery process
        immediately," he said as they awaited the test results
        after a top aide he spent substantial time with this
        week tested positive for COVID-19.
    </p>
    <p>
    Trump's comments came after he confirmed that Hope
    Hicks, one his closest aides, had tested positive for
    the virus Thursday. Hicks began feeling mild symptoms
    during the plane ride home from a rally in Minnesota
    Wednesday evening, according to an administration
    official, who spoke on condition of anonymity to
    disclose private information. She was quarantined away
    from others on the plane and her diagnosis was
    confirmed Thursday, the person said.
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Any chance you would like to show what you have tried so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64213724/how-can-i-render-date-in-the-browser-using-day-js - that's your question with an answer you accepted

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
dayjs("DATE_TIME_STRING").fromNow()
```

ex: `dayjs("2020-10-14 03:03:03").fromNow()`, this would give you the output as `a day ago`.